Почему не создается файл профиля firefox в командной строке?
Задача создать профиль Firefox с указанным именем, в указанной папке через командную строку.
Версия firefox установленная в системе: 132.0.2 (64-разрядный)
Путь до исполняемого файла: c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Вот здесь на wiki есть описание ключей командной строки
В результате команда
"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -CreateProfile 
"vsport71 c:\_br\_firefox\vsport71"

Выдает ошибку
Unexpected token '-CreateProfile' in expression or statement.

Такого ключа '-CreateProfile' теперь не существует?

А что тут мои вопросы еще и править будут??? Может тот кто исправлял сразу и ответит, раз знает как правильно задавать вопросы?

Я поправила ваш вопрос, так как код и текст ошибки принято оборачивать в обратные кавычки. Это есть в справке. Ответа на ваш вопрос я не знаю.
